# ASP.NET MVC from validation for related entity

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, jquery-validate

I am not sure if it is a bug or not but MVC 5 (also 3 and 4) is not handling client side form validation if an entity includes another entity itself. So my scenario is to create a View Model which reference other Domain Models having validation annotations like [Required] etc. Like:

```
public class Membership
    {
        public Company Company { get; set; }

        public User User{ get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "{0} can not be empty")]
        public string Type{ get; set; }
    }

    public class User 
        {
            [Required]
            public string UserName {get; set;}
            //..... so on
        }

    public class Company
        {
            [Required]
            public string CompanyName {get; set;}
            //..... so on
        }
```

When I use Membership entity as a ViewModel for my registration form validation only works for Type attribute but not for the related entities User and Company.

According to my experience, this view model creates the below client dom objects for the related entities:

```
<input aria-invalid="true" aria-required="true" data-val="true" data-val-required="Company Name can not be empty" id="Company.CompanyName" name="Company.CompanyName" value="" type="text">
```

As you may clearly notice that there are dots (.) between the object and attribute in id and name dom attributes. I am sure about that the jquery can not read this kind selectors (having dots inside) which may cause malfunction for the validator.

Do you have any idea?

**UPDATE**

Form section of my view is briefly as below:

```
  @using (Html.BeginForm("Membership", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "seperate-sections fill-up" }))
                    {
              <div class="form-group">
                                    <div class="input-group addon-left">
                                        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="icon-user"></i></span>
                                        @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Company.CompanyName)
                                    </div>
                                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Company.CompanyName)
                                </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                                    <div class="input-group addon-left">
                                        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="icon-user"></i></span>
                                        @Html.EditorFor(m => m.User.UserName)
                                    </div>
                                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.User.UserName)
                                </div>
```

}

Included scripts are:

```
<script src="/scripts/jquery.validate.min.js?v=8d16f4c1ca0f151" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/scripts/jquery.validate.additional-methods.js?v=8d1428a3c3f3399" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js?v=8d1765d406515b4" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js?v=8d16f4c32f4bcea" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: You are doing something wrong.  MVC has methods to handle this properly.  Please include your view code so we can see how you're creating your forms.  My guess is that you're not using BeginForm(), but rather just `<form>` element.

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch I put my view on the question also but unfortunately it includes BeginForm also.. :S

Comment: Do you happen to have any EditorTemplates defined for string?  Try changing from EditorFor to TextBoxFor to rule out a templating issue.

Comment: You were absolutely right!! Thank you. I did create editortemplates which include id as: //@id = ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix, so I've changed it as //@id = ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix.Replace('.', '_') and working now!